# crossfilter order by count

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, crossfilter

I'm trying to make a barchart of data count each month, the data looks as following:

```
[
  {
    "key_as_string": "2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1383264000000,
    "doc_count": 1,
    "dd": "2013-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1385856000000,
    "doc_count": 0,
    "dd": "2013-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1388534400000,
    "doc_count": 0,
    "dd": "2014-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1391212800000,
    "doc_count": 2,
    "dd": "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1393632000000,
    "doc_count": 15,
    "dd": "2014-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1396310400000,
    "doc_count": 20,
    "dd": "2014-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1398902400000,
    "doc_count": 8,
    "dd": "2014-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1401580800000,
    "doc_count": 5,
    "dd": "2014-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1404172800000,
    "doc_count": 10,
    "dd": "2014-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1406851200000,
    "doc_count": 0,
    "dd": "2014-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1409529600000,
    "doc_count": 11,
    "dd": "2014-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1412121600000,
    "doc_count": 17,
    "dd": "2014-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1414800000000,
    "doc_count": 7,
    "dd": "2014-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1417392000000,
    "doc_count": 7,
    "dd": "2014-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1420070400000,
    "doc_count": 17,
    "dd": "2015-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1422748800000,
    "doc_count": 10,
    "dd": "2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1425168000000,
    "doc_count": 5,
    "dd": "2015-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1427846400000,
    "doc_count": 2,
    "dd": "2015-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1430438400000,
    "doc_count": 5,
    "dd": "2015-05-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1433116800000,
    "doc_count": 3,
    "dd": "2015-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1435708800000,
    "doc_count": 14,
    "dd": "2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1438387200000,
    "doc_count": 5,
    "dd": "2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1441065600000,
    "doc_count": 10,
    "dd": "2015-09-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1443657600000,
    "doc_count": 10,
    "dd": "2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1446336000000,
    "doc_count": 15,
    "dd": "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1448928000000,
    "doc_count": 6,
    "dd": "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1451606400000,
    "doc_count": 18,
    "dd": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1454284800000,
    "doc_count": 15,
    "dd": "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "key_as_string": "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "key": 1456790400000,
    "doc_count": 4,
    "dd": "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

then I do the following:

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);

$scope.dimension = ndx.dimension(function (d) {
    return d.key;
});

$scope.orderdbycount = $scope.dimension.group().reduceCount(function(d) {
    if (d.doc_count > 1) {
        $log.debug(d);
    }
    return d.doc_count;
});
$scope.scale = d3.time.scale().domain([$scope.dimension.top(1)[0].dd, $scope.dimension.bottom(1)[0].dd]);
```

but nothing is every logged; and my orderbyCount has only value's of 1

I'm doing the following for html:

```
<div dc-chart="barChart"
        dc-width="700"
        dc-height="150"
        dc-name="'volumeChart2'"
        dc-dimension="dimension"
        dc-group="orderdbycount"
        dc-x="scale"
        dc-x-units="d3.time.months"></div>
```

this is with the 'angular-dc' module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`reduceCount` just gives you the count of the number of records. It doesn't take an accessor so your `$log` never gets called. I believe you are looking for `reduceSum`.